# How to Insert DataGrid Record from another User Control

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to insert some record into `DataGrid` grid1 which is in Child1 User Control and I want to fill this data Grid record From another User Control Child2

My code on click as Below,

```
public void cmbEventReceiver_SelectionChanged (object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)   
{
    ComboBoxItem typeItem = (ComboBoxItem)cmbEventReceiver.SelectedItem;

    if (contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.Rows.Count==0 )
    {
        contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.Columns.Add("ID");
        contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.Columns.Add("Name");
    }           

    contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.Rows.Add(new Object[] { typeItem.Tag, typeItem.Content });
    contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.AcceptChanges();

    // contentTypeDataControl.grdEventReferences.ItemsSource = contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers.DefaultView;
    //contentTypeDataControl.grdEventReferences.Items.Add(new Object[] { typeItem.Tag, typeItem.Content });
    contentTypeDataControl.FillDataGridEventReceiver(contentTypeDataControl.dtEventReceivers);
    contentTypeDataControl.ppFieldReference.IsOpen = false;
    contentTypeDataControl.wrapPanel.Children.RemoveAt(1);
    contentTypeDataControl.wrapPanel.Focus();            
}

public void FillDataGridEventReceiver(DataTable dt)
{
    grdEventReferences.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView;
}
```

But it's not display anything in my grid.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a problem in correct databinding.

as a simple example for a DataGrid binding I would use the following structure:

viewmodel.cs

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public ObservableCollection<MyGridObject> GridItems {get; set;}

    public void OnSomethingHappens(MyGridObject newObjectToAdd){
        GridItems.Add(newObjectToAdd);
    }
}

public class MyGridObject {
    public int ID {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

your model should look like:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding GridItems}" />
```

Thats the way to deal with data in WPF. Don't try to act the Controls from codebehind directly. If you like to do this, you should use WinForms.

Comment: I agree with @Fabian. The UserControls have nothing to do with your databinding. You just need to update your Datasource in Viewmodel.